# Java: How edit button positions in JOptionPane.showInputDialog?

Tags: input, dialog, show, joptionpane

How do you edit the button positions in the JOptionPane.showInputDialog pop up?

Are there arguments that you can put into the parameters?

```
  String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame.getFrame(), "Please enter a value from 1 to 9");

  if (inputValue == null) { // Cancel button
    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I just had to add extra arguments to make it a plain message, but how do you reposition the buttons?

```
String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame.getFrame(), "Please enter a value from 1 to 9","", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```